# Wrap element after image with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html markup and what I want to achieve is that the content after the  tag gets wrapped in a div

```
<div class="imageblock">
<img alt="image-alt" src="/images/image.jpg">
Image description
</div>
```

So the final code needs to be something like this:

```
<div class="imageblock">
<img alt="image-alt" src="/images/image.jpg">
<div class="captionDiv">Image description</div>
</div>
```

I've tried a lot of jquery scripts.

This is what I have this far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.imageblock img').after().wrapInner('<div class="captionDiv"/>');
});
</script>
```

The reason that I need to do this with jQuery, is that I do not want to touch the core code (it cannot be overwritten, and is not future proof).

Any clues?

Comment: If you've tried stuff, post what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.imageblock').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
}).wrap('<div class="captionDiv" />');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xF6NA/)**

This produces:

```
<div class="imageblock">
    <img alt="image-alt" src="/images/image.jpg">
    <div class="captionDiv">Image description</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But will wrap all nonempty text nodes in the imageblock, not just the one after the img tag.

Comment: So it depends on how representative the example is. Question title says element after image. If the example is exemplary, then eq(2) will do the trick even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using contents() and .eq()

```
$('.imageblock').each( function( ) 
{
    $( this ).contents().eq(2).wrap('<div class="captionNew"/>')
});​
```

( This assumes that the text you want to wrap is the second element in the div, not counting the element you are inside of )

EDIT ----- I made some syntax goofs :p

```
$( document ).ready( function( )
{
    $('.imageblock').each( function( ) 
    {
        alert( $(this).html());
        $( this ).contents().eq(2).wrap('<div class="captionDiv" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: Should be lowercase b -> imageblock

Comment: @WNRDesign I fixed it up, had some syntax errors :P, and this works now in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xF6NA/5/ ---- Added the alert to make sure I was grabbing the element properly

Answer (score 1):

If you literally want to wrap only those nodes directly following the img tags:

```
var $contents = $(".imageblock").contents();
$('.imageblock img').each(function () {
    $contents.eq($contents.index(this) + 1).wrap('<div class="captionDiv"/>');
});
```

[<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Bs72L/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too happy about this code as it is extremely dependent on the example HTML you have given. However, this code does produce the HTML structure you described:

```
// cache the container element
var imageblock = $( ".imageblock" );

// copy all children (but not the raw text) 
var elems = imageblock.children();

// remove all existing elements (but not the raw text) 
imageblock.children().remove();  

// wrap the raw text with a div
imageblock.wrapInner( "<div class='captionDiv'>" ); 

// bring back the original child elements
imageblock.prepend( elems );
```

### [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6rYP2/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed works. Except. I have to do this for 3 containers. Any solution for that?

Comment: You can just iterate over each `.imageblock` that you have on your page. The code should work in the same manner - just make sure that the `imageblock` variable references each container. [Take a look at this example](http://jsfiddle.net/6rYP2/2/).

Answer (score 0):

My answer shows a working wrap here, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/totallytotallyamazing/nkzfqv0b/).

HTML:

```
<div class="imageblock">
<img alt="image-alt" src="/images/image.jpg">
Image description
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".imageblock").contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3; })
            .wrap("<div class='captionDiv'/>");
});
```

CSS:

```
.captionDiv{background-color:yellow;}
```

Comment: You don't need the bit with the parent: `(".imageblock").contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType == 3; }).wrap("<div class='captionDiv'/>");` is good enough. BUT you're wrapping any text node in the imageblock, not just the one after the img element.

Comment: @flup Thanks for pointing this out. To see in action I will run test.

Comment: @flup Thanks Again! I ran the test - you are right! Looked at your solution and props to you.